# How to deal with landscape orientation prior to child view navigation

Tags: iphone, ios, orientation, tableview

I have a table and when the table is clicked it to goes to a child view which display a number of labels etc. I have set it up so when when the user is currently viewing the detail view and they rotate the objects rearrange themselves and this works well. However how do I deal with the situation that the phone is rotated during while displaying the table and then the user clicks to move to the detailed view. At the moment it tries to show the portrait view and very badly. Any suggestions welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use `[[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation]` during the detail controller's viewWillAppear: method to decide if you need to call the code that handles rearranging objects when rotation happens.